# Exclude Widget from Listener in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a `Listener` widget to detect scroll gestures on a `Column` of widgets. Let's say my screen looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is that the `Listener` detect all gestures on all widgets except for gestures on the orange area. What is the best practice for this? How can I exclude this orange widget from the `Listener` region?

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      home: Foo(),
    );
  }
}

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Foo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Foo> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerMove: (event) => print(event),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(children: [
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow)),
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.orange)),
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow)),
              ]),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```